# Trigger jQuery event after .NET button validates correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a wizard with a few steps and a few buttons like so:

```
<asp:linkButton CssClass="btn-primary" ValidationGroup="contact" Text="Next" ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" />
```

This control validates a few input fields. When no errors are thrown, so all input fields are filled in correctly I want to use jQuery to show the next step and update a progressbar.

How can I call a jQuery function after the lbtnNext button throws no validation errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546745/check-result-of-asp-net-validator-clientside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var valid = false;

if(Page_ClientValidate(validationgroup))
{
   valid = true;
}

if(valid)
{

}
```

Comment: YashPatel, I have updated your code, the casing of `var` and `if` was wrong, as was your locally scoped variable, and you should use a boolean not an integer for the condition.